# Google App Script. JSON from BigQuery.Jobs.query response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I want to get JSON string from a response of BigQuery.Jobs.query. Are there any easy ways?

Google App Script

```
var request = {
    query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' + 'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'
};
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
```

What I want to take a JSON text from `queryResults`

```
[
  {
    "word": "counterfeit",
    "word_count": "28"
  },
  {
    "word": "remembrance",
    "word_count": "24"
  },
  {
    "word": "countenance",
    "word_count": "24"
  },
```

---

It worked thanks to Henrique Abreu.

```
var request = {
  query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' + 'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'
};
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
Logger.log(parseSimpleResults(queryResults));

[
   {
      word_count=28,
      word=counterfeit
   },
   {
      word_count=24,
      word=remembrance
   }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested this with more BigQuery query results, but it should work fine for "simple" results.

```
function parseSimpleResults(results) {
  var names = results.schema.fields.map(function(field){ return field.name; });
  return results.rows.map(function(row) {
    var obj = {};
    for( var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; ++i ) {
      obj[names[i]] = row.f[i].v;
    }
    return obj;
  });
}
```

Just pass your `queryResults` variable to it and you should get your nice array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

just one of directions for you to explore:

```
local obj = JSON.parse(queryResults)
return obj.rows[1].f[1].v, obj.rows[1].f[2].v
```

Comment: I think `queryResults` is already an object, therefore there's no need to JSON.parse it.